# Getting undefined at the start of an array in my GAS invoice generator using Google Docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

My script gets furniture prices & details from a Google spreadsheet and brings it into a Google docs add-on, this shows a sidebar where you select the range of furniture and spits out prices into the sidebar with an input field for the quantity once you hit generate invoice on the sidebar it then populates the Google doc table with the unit code, name, price, and quantity.

It's all working except for the first iteration of unitCode unitName unitPrice etc has undefined before it says the unitCode, unitPrice, unitName etc. Sorry about the mess of code it's very much a work in progress and hasn't been tidied or sample code really removed.

Also I feel like there's probably a much easier way to achieve what im trying to do, probably with just using G sheets itself so definitely open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance.
Photo of how undefined shows[image]

Heres the HTML that sends to the GS file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <!-- The CSS package above applies Google styling to buttons and other elements. -->

    <style>
    .units {
    margin-top:20px;
    width:100%;
 }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="sidebar branding-below">
    <label>Client Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name"><br>
    <label>Client Phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_phone" id="client_phone"><br>
    <label>Client Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="client_email" id="client_email"><br>
 <!-- Multiple Radios -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="furntype">Furniture Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="furntype-0">
      <input type="radio" name="furntype" id="furntype-0" value="0" checked="checked">
      6S
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <label for="furntype-1">
      <input type="radio" name="furntype" id="furntype-1" value="1">
      6S Compact
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<span id="theFurnType"></span>



    
      <form>
</form>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      /**
       * On document load, assign click handlers to each button and try to load the
       * user's origin and destination language preferences if previously set.
       */
      $(function() {


  
        $('input:radio').click(function() {
        
        var sheetDataz = google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(err){
        console.error("error occured", err);
    })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(res){
    var tab = '<div class="units"><div >';
    var price = res[2];
    var theUnitCode = res[0];

    $.each(res[1], function(index, value){
    var aPrice = price[index];
   var thePrice = parseFloat(aPrice).toFixed(2);
   var unitCode = theUnitCode[index];
   tab += '<span>'+value+'</span><input type="text" class="unit"  unitcode="'+unitCode+'" unitname="'+value+'" id="'+index+'" price="'+thePrice+'" value="0" style="float:right; width:40px;"><hr>';
    });
    tab += '<br><button type="button" id="doInvoice">Create Invoice</button></div>';
    $('#theFurnType').html(tab);
            $('#doInvoice').click(replaceIt);
    }).getSheetData($(this).val());
  });
  
  
          function replaceIt() {
      var client_name = $('#client_name').val();
      var client_phone = $('#client_phone').val();
      var client_email = $('#client_email').val();
      var acr = client_name.match(/\b(\w)/g); 
        var invoice_num = acr.join('');
        var date = GetTodayDate();
        var invoice_num = invoice_num+'_'+date;
        var theUnits = {};
        $('.unit').each(function() {
         theUnits.unitQuantity += $(this).val()+',';
         theUnits.unitPrice += $(this).attr("price")+',';
         theUnits.unitName += $(this).attr("unitname")+',';
         theUnits.unitCode += $(this).attr("unitcode")+',';
        });
              google.script.run.doReplace(client_name,client_phone,client_email,invoice_num,date,theUnits);
      }

  
  
      });
 
 
 

function GetTodayDate() {
   var tdate = new Date();
   var dd = tdate.getDate(); //yields day
   var MM = tdate.getMonth(); //yields month
   var yyyy = tdate.getFullYear(); //yields year
   var currentDate= dd + "-" +( MM+1) + "-" + yyyy;

   return currentDate;
}





    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Heres the GS file

```js
/**
 * @NotOnlyCurrentDoc
 *
 * The above comment directs Apps Script to limit the scope of file
 * access for this add-on. It specifies that this add-on will only
 * attempt to read or modify the files in which the add-on is used,
 * and not all of the user's files. The authorization request message
 * presented to users will reflect this limited scope.
 */

/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
      .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Runs when the add-on is installed.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall triggers always
 *     run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen triggers may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
 *     AuthMode.NONE.)
 */
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 * This method is only used by the regular add-on, and is never called by
 * the mobile add-on version.
 */
function showSidebar() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sidebar')
      .setTitle('Infinity Invoice Generator');
  DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

/**
 * Gets the text the user has selected. If there is no selection,
 * this function displays an error message.
 *
 * @return {Array.<string>} The selected text.
 */

function getSheetData(furnType) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1jLpJ35Szy6R3DDVVuOmi0Cw462ukI2DWzHG6VxYWd1g');
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  if(furnType == 0) {
    var ranges = [sheets[0].getRange('A2:A11').getValues(), sheets[0].getRange('B2:B11').getValues(), sheets[0].getRange('H2:H11').getValues()];
  }
  if(furnType == 1) {
      var ranges = [sheets[1].getRange('A2:A10').getValues(), sheets[1].getRange('B2:B10').getValues(), sheets[1].getRange('H2:H10').getValues()];
  }
  return ranges;
}

      function doReplace(client_name,client_phone,client_email,invoice_num,date,theUnits) { 
      var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
        

        
        var tables = body.getTables();
        var table = tables[2];
        

var unitQuantity = theUnits.unitQuantity.split(',');
var unitCode = theUnits.unitCode.split(',');
var unitName = theUnits.unitName.split(',');
var unitPrice = theUnits.unitPrice.split(',');
        
        var style1 = {};
style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial';
style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#D9D9D9';
  style1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#000000';
        
 

        var style2 = {};
style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Arial';
style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 12;
style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#F3F3F3';
style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = 'CENTER';
style2[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#000000';
        
        
   var i;
for (i = 0; i < unitQuantity.length; i++) {
      var tr = table.appendTableRow();
        var td = tr.appendTableCell(''+unitCode[i]+'').setAttributes(style1);
        var td = tr.appendTableCell(''+unitName[i]+'').setAttributes(style2);
        var td = tr.appendTableCell(''+unitPrice[i]+'').setAttributes(style2);
        var td = tr.appendTableCell(''+unitQuantity[i]+'').setAttributes(style2);
}

       
        
        
       body.replaceText("{{ClientName}}", client_name);
        body.replaceText("{{ClientPhone}}", client_phone);
         body.replaceText("{{ClientEmail}}", client_email);
         body.replaceText("{{InvoiceNumber}}", invoice_num);
         body.replaceText("{{CurrentDate}}", date);
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proble is with `replaceIt` function, specifically the way you are building `theUnits` object. **Initialize each property within object with empty string** and that will fix the issue:

```js
function replaceIt() {
  var client_name = $('#client_name').val();
  var client_phone = $('#client_phone').val();
  var client_email = $('#client_email').val();
  var acr = client_name.match(/\b(\w)/g);
  var invoice_num = acr.join('');
  var date = GetTodayDate();
  var invoice_num = invoice_num + '_' + date;
  var theUnits = {
    unitQuantity: "",
    unitPrice: "",
    unitName: "",
    unitCode: ""
  };
  $('.unit').each(function() {
    theUnits.unitQuantity += $(this).val() + ',';
    theUnits.unitPrice += $(this).attr("price") + ',';
    theUnits.unitName += $(this).attr("unitname") + ',';
    theUnits.unitCode += $(this).attr("unitcode") + ',';
  });
  google.script.run.doReplace(client_name, client_phone, client_email, invoice_num, date, theUnits);
}
```